# migrate c++/cli project to .NET 7

Tags: wpf, c++-cli, .net-7.0

There is a C++/Cli solution that contains C+/CLI and some WPF projects. They target .NET Framework 4.8. 
It's been working for years. We've tried to migrate it to  latest .NET 7, but not successed. There are some examples of migration in the Internet , for example [C++/CLI  Windows Forms migration sample](https://github.com/mjrousos/CppCliMigrationSample.git)

This sample is old and targeting .NET Core 3.1, but we've managed to migrate it to .NET 7. Successfully ran it and experimented with it.
 Problem is that it is for WindowsForms. Nothing wrong for WindowsForms, but it crashes in runtime , when we added a sample WPF project to this solution and trying to create an instance of WPF window inside of C++/CLI.
Tried to google: and everywhere samples of running **WindowsForms** **on .NET Core** within C++/CLI execution context (or .net 6+) **not WPF**.
Is it possible at all to run WPF (consume wpf project) in C++/CLI what targets .NET 7 (or .NET 6 at least)?

Comment: Did you see this link to [Upgrade a WPF app to .NET 7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/migration/?view=netdesktop-7.0)

Comment: @MarkBenningfield there is no problem upgrade it to .net7, there is a problem to run wpf (.net7) inside of managed c++